# No permission to git clone?

Tags: git, gitlab

What is possible problem, if I have SSH key, and trying to git clone one folder from git lab, but I still dont have permission for it ?

Comment: Did you try to ssh to your gitlab instance to see if that is working: `ssh -T <user>@<gitlab-host>`? Did you add your user to the project you're trying to clone? Is this user configured with the correct public key? We need much more information to be able to help you.

Comment: maybe problem is when I try ssh -T etc. result is Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '137.116.75.53' to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to GitLab, <user>!
and this user is not me, but someone else who was using this computer on the same project. I added my user to the project, also configured with correct public key

Comment: So you do `ssh -T <userA>@<host>` and you get `Welcome <userB>!`, is that correct? I would check the file `~/.ssh/config` if the user is not overridden in a setting. Try to add `-v` to the ssh command and look for a line starting with `debug1: Authenticating to (...) as (...)` which user is reported here?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?